# Exclude posts with certain meta data from search results

Tags: search, meta-query, exclude

I'm trying to exclude al posts with certain meta data from the search results but so far it's not working.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
function ZoekGeenLegeItems( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || $query->get( 'post_type' ) != 'item' )
        return $query;

    $query->set('meta_query', array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'KEY_itm_leeg'
            ,'value' => '0'
        )
    ));
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ZoekGeenLegeItems');
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

First, the `pre_get_posts` hook is an **action** and not a filter.

Then the `meta_query` parameter should contain the `relation` **only if** there is more than one inner meta_query array ([codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)).

Finally you do not need to return the `$query` argument as it is passed by reference to your callback function.

Your code should look like this:

```
function ZoekGeenLegeItems( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || $query->get( 'post_type' ) != 'item' )
        return;

    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'KEY_itm_leeg',
            'value' => '0'
        )
    ) );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','ZoekGeenLegeItems');
```

Comment: This does not work either.
Could it have something to do with the fact the the '0' is the result of an unchecked checkbox?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I just ran this code in a test setup and it works. Is your `$query->set` run? if you add a `var_dump($query->get('meta_query'));` at the end of the function, does it prints the `meta_query` array? if not it means that the `if` statement is true and the query is not altered

Comment: Depending on your meta data save function, the value could be absent or `false` which might not match `'0'`. You could verify the value is as expected, or add back the `relation` clause and arrays for the other possible values like `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`.